# Postgres rule or trigger to update multiple rows after update of single row

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a postgres table in the form of

| id | x_loc |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 12.7 |
| 1500 | 13.2 |
| 1001 | 12.7 |
| 1502 | 13.2 |
| 1002 | 12.8 |

and want to make a rule or trigger that will update the x_loc column for all rows that meet a certain criteria whenever I update a single row's x_loc value.

In my case the first 3 digits of the 'id' column can be read as being a group that *should* always have the same x_loc value in the table. So if I update the x_loc for id 1000, it should also update the x_loc for 1001 and 1002 to the same value. If I update the x_loc for 1502, it should set the x_loc for 1500 to the same value.

I realize that this means the x_loc is duplicated for a lot of entries, and that a better practice might be to separate x_loc into a different table and create a new 'id' column that just uses the first 3 digits, but I think that's going to complicate things with other queries and the rest of the database more than I want to deal with.

I tried the follow RULE but get the infinite recursion detected error for obvious reasons. Is there any way to go about this with rules/triggers? Thanks

> CREATE OR REPLACE RULE x_loc_update AS on UPDATE TO tbl_test
> WHERE NEW.x_loc<>OLD.x_loc
> DO INSTEAD
> UPDATE tbl_test SET
> x_loc=NEW.x_loc
> WHERE left(id,3)=left(NEW.id,3)

Comment: Would it not be easier just to do `UPDATE tbl_test SET x_loc = 12.9 WHERE left('1000', 3) = left(id::varchar, 3)`? You are getting the recursion because the `x_loc` is changed which runs the rule which changes `x_loc` which runs the rule and so on.

Comment: Yeah, that's a possibility, but in practice I'm mostly editing these values in other applications (gis & access forms), and not by directly running an update query. So I'd have to find out how to change the query that gets sent to postgres when I edit a value in one of these apps. The trigger you posted below works well. It saves me a lot of time not having to make the same edit 2 or 3 times for each one. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `AFTER` trigger:

```
create table loc_tbl (id integer, x_loc numeric);
insert into loc_tbl values (1000,12.7), (1500,13.2), (1001,12.7), (1502,13.2), (1002,12.8);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.x_loc_fnc()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.x_loc != OLD.x_loc THEN
        UPDATE 
            loc_tbl
        SET 
            x_loc = NEW.x_loc
        WHERE 
            left(NEW.id::varchar, 3) = left(id::varchar, 3);
    END IF;
RETURN null;
END;

$function$
;

CREATE TRIGGER 
    loc_trg 
AFTER UPDATE ON 
    loc_tbl 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION 
    x_loc_fnc();

select * from loc_tbl ;
  id  | x_loc 
------+-------
 1000 |  12.7
 1500 |  13.2
 1001 |  12.7
 1502 |  13.2
 1002 |  12.8

UPDATE loc_tbl SET x_loc = 12.9 WHERE id = 1000;
UPDATE 1

select * from loc_tbl ;
  id  | x_loc 
------+-------
 1500 |  13.2
 1502 |  13.2
 1001 |  12.9
 1002 |  12.9
 1000 |  12.9
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a function here
and update your ids,
if you think it can be duplicated, then use lead and add +1 with it for the others.
I hope it will work.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. As in the question title it says I need rule or trigger, which is the right solution since it's auto called each time an update happens unlike functions which should be called explicitly each time. Please make  sure you understand the question before answering as in : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer